# How to re-install ruby on Mac Snow Leopard?

Tags: mac, ruby

I Accidentally corrupted my system install of ruby and cant find out how to fix this. Any ideas?

Basically i was trying to install Redmine on my system and i accidentally copied a file into /usr/bin/ruby which somehow altered/corrupted the ruby executable located:

/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current/usr/bin/ruby

Not sure what happened but the ruby executable is the only file that was modified in that dir  now no ruby commands work. Not sure if i overwrote it or what?

Running 10.6.6 64 bit.

Comment: How did you install it? Via MacPorts? From source?

Comment: Pretty sure its installed by default. Although perhaps it was Xcode?

Comment: Can you give us a little more insight on what you mean by corrupted?

Comment: Edited question

Comment: Wait, so did you overwrite the symlink at `/usr/bin/ruby` or did you overwrite the original in `/System/Library/…`?

Comment: The original...

Answer (score 1):

Here's the file from my i7 MBP on 10.6.6: http://d.pr/o8sG

Answer (score 0):

first Uninstall ruby. and then use [rvm](http://beginrescueend.com/) (ruby enVironment manager) to install various rubies and manage gems.